# Prevent server from closing socket?

Tags: python, sockets

I have written a small python script to make a set number of connections to a server. This works fine but I can see in a packet capture that the server is sending a FIN and closing the connection after data is received, can this be avoided. I want to keep the connection open until I close it ?

```
def create_socket(COUNT):
    sock = socket.socket()
    host = '1.2.3.4'
    port = port
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((host,port))
    sock.send(str.encode("Connection " + str(COUNT) + " connected successfully"))  
    return sock

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while ATTEMPTS > 0:
            server_sock = create_socket(COUNT)
            print("Connection attempt " + str(COUNT))
            socket_list.append(server_sock)  
            ATTEMPTS -= 1
            COUNT += 1
    except:
        RESPONSE = 'Failed, unable to connect'
    finally:
        print(RESPONSE)
        print("Waiting 15 seconds before closing all connections")
        time.sleep(15)
        server_sock.close()
```

Comment: Where is `socket_list` initialized ? And don't use base `except`s

Comment: remark, you put all open connections into a list, but you only close the last socket `server_sock.close()`

Comment: Previously the client connections where closing, I tried adding them to a list so garbage collecton wouldnt close each connection for every iteration of the loop

Comment: Are you in control of the server?  Generally there is no way to force from the client side the server do something it does not want to do. If the server is programmed to receive one request, process it and then always close the connection, this is what happens and there is no way around that.